# Beamer and enumerate package

Tags: beamer, enumerate

The following example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[H1]
  \item
  \item[H2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

results (with all packages updated from CTAN) in a slide with a list where the second item is labeled "H2" (as expected), while the first item is labeled "H1", but in a smaller font and in a bullet. This has not been like this a year ago, and I assume it is not the intended behaviour of the enumerate package. Does anyone have an idea how I globally (I have a long document where I use enumerate a lot) could ensure that the enumerate package yields the same results as giving the label to the item command?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Excuse me but I have not understood your question :(. Could you put add an image for your problem?

Comment: This is the problematic line https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/561ebfeca410a68c57179bd8ed1fdb85c9b703d2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of the enumerate mini template was changed in this commit: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/561ebfeca410a68c57179bd8ed1fdb85c9b703d2

To revert to the previous behaviour, you could do `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate mini template}{\insertenumlabel}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate mini template}{\insertenumlabel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}[H1]
  \item
  \item[H2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]